# Get associative array from serialised cookie

Tags: php

None of the details inside the details inside of the array would compromise security and the one person which will be using this website will be using the latest of web browsers, in-case you are thinking about debating security at me about this.

I've tried multiple methods of gathering an array which was serialised using the standard serialise function, this is what I used:

```
        $mooring = serialize($mooring);
        setcookie("mooringdata", $mooring, time()+3600);
```

I've checked my cookie manager and it seems like it worked successfully in storing the details I required but it looks like it has been url-encoded. I've tried multiple methods of getting my original array from the stored cookie but it *NEVER* works, even when my code says that it should!

I've tried these following blocks of code, separated by a newline to symbolise another attempt:

```
$data = unserialize(urldecode($_COOKIE['mooringdata'])));
print_r($data);
```

This returns blank.

```
$data = array(unserialize(urldecode($_COOKIE['mooringdata']))));
print_r($data);
```

This returns "Array ( [0] => )"
And the list goes on, if there is an alternative to passing an array from page to page without using GET's or POST's I'm all ears, but if you think you have a solution, please reply!

Comment: What does `$_COOKIE['mooringdata']` look like, what about a simple `unserialize($_COOKIE['mooringdata'])`?

Answer (score 1):

For starters it automatically decodes the cookie before putting it in `$_COOKIE`, so in theory just `unserialize($_COOKIE['mooringdata'])` should work. But you probably should use `$_SESSION` to store this data, so that the browser doesn't have to constantly send the data back and forth for no good reason.

Comment: Once the cookie has been used, I'd simply remove it. Regarding using unserialize, it still returns blank.